# Add all columns form one dataframe to another without joining on a key/index

Tags: python, pandas

Having two dataframes `df1` and `df2` (same number of rows) how can we, very simply, take all the columns from `df2` and add them to `df1`? Using join, we are joining them on the index or a given column, but assuming their index's are completely different and they have no columns in common. Is that doable (without the obvious way of looping over each column in `df2`and add them as new to `df1`)?

EDIT: added an example.

Note; no index, column names are mentioned since it should not matter (thats is the "problem").

```
df1= [[1,3,2,
      [11,20,33]]

df2 = [["bird",np.nan,37,np.sqrt(2)]
       ["dog",0.123,3.14,0]]

pd.some_operation(df1,df2)
#[[1,3,2,"bird",np.nan,37,np.sqrt(2)]
#[11,20,33,"dog",0.123,3.14,0]]
```

Comment: You can use `pd.concat` with axis = 1 [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: What's the criteria for matching a row from df1 to a row from df2? Are they in the same order? If so - pd.concat. If not - you'll have to use join / merge.

Comment: In any case, please include some sample data and expected output.

Comment: There is no matching criteria - I just want the first row of `df2` to be right after the first row of `df1`

Answer (score 0):

Samples:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
}, index = list('QRSTUW'))


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
}, index = list('KLMNOP'))
```

Pandas always use index values if use `join` or `concat` by `axis=1`, so for correct alignement is necessary create same index values:

```
df = df1.join(df2.set_index(df1.index))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_index(df1.index)], axis=1)
```

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
Q  a  4  7  1  5  a
R  b  5  8  3  3  a
S  c  4  9  5  6  a
T  d  5  4  7  9  b
U  e  5  2  1  2  b
W  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Or create default index in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df = df1.reset_index(drop=True).join(df2.reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b
```

Comment: I really think it is odd that you cannot just concat them without having to specify a link index/columns. Numpy can do it so easy, but I kinda do not want to convert it to a numpy ndarray, cat them, make it a dataframe again

Comment: @CutePoison - Yop, if want use pandas there is always index/columns alignement.